# Where to put media resource and start media player?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I want to play a song in a Xamarin app using the standard android media player.

I've got two questions that i haven't been able to answer myself:

1. Here do I put the media file (.mp3-file) or how do i link to the file (it's also saved on my SD-Card) I tried saving it in the raw-folder, but that doesn't seem to work
2. How do I correctly launch the player? Either my code doesn't work or the player doesn't find the file because it isn't stored correctly.

However, that's the method I use to prepare the media player:

```
protected MediaPlayer player;

public void StartPlayer() {
    if (player == null) {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.SetDataSource("Ressources.raw.test");
        player.Prepare();
        player.Start();
        text = "Running";
    } else {
        player.Reset();
        player.SetDataSource("Ressources.raw.test");
        player.Prepare();
        player.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I tried saving it in the raw-folder, but that doesn't seem to work

You can't directly use string "Ressources.raw.test" as the `DataSource`. If you need play a song from `Resource/Raw` folder, here is two solutions.

## Solution 1:

You could try using [MediaPlayer.Create(Context context, int resid)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int))
 method:

> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.

Usage：

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.test);
player.Start();
```

## Solution 2:

Convert your `Resource/Raw/test` path to `Android.Net.Uri`:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.test);
player.SetDataSource(this, uri2);
player.Prepare();
player.Start();
```

> how do I link to the file (it's also saved on my SD-Card)

## Solution:

Try using [SetDataSource (Context context, Uri uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) method, for example:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();

//My file path is Path == file:///storage/emulated/0/netease/cloudmusic/Music/love.MP3
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/netease/cloudmusic/Music/love.MP3");

player.SetDataSource(this, uri);
player.Prepare();
player.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D As I said, I'm new to this

Comment: @GodmasterofDoom, if there's any problem, please feel free to ask. :)