# Using file from android project in media Player

Tags: xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MUbp.png) i have a mobile application that is dedicated to playing articles using `MediaPlayer`. I am trying to set the pause between individual sentences however i keep getting n`ull reference` at the `pausesPlayer` so accesing the mp3 files in my `droid project from shared project` must be wrong. Please do you have any experience with how to acess the file in droid without Main Activity

```
MediaPlayer.Create(MainActivity.Instance, Resource.Raw.silent_1);

public static void SetPauseBetweenSentences(int timeout)
{
    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        pausesPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (timeout != 0)
        {
            switch (timeout)
            {
                case 1:
                    pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("AT.Droid/Resources/raw/silent_1"));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("AT.Droid/Resources/raw/silent_2"));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("AT.Droid/Resources/raw/silent_3"));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("AT.Droid/Resources/raw/silent_4"));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("AT.Droid/Resources/raw/silent_5"));
                    break;
            }
            pausesPlayer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://AT.Droid/Resources/raw/silent_1"));
```

and

```
pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://AT/Resources/raw/silent_1"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.mediaplayer.create?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_Media_MediaPlayer_Create_Android_Content_Context_System_Int32_), you can use:

Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id.

```
public static Android.Media.MediaPlayer Create (Android.Content.Context context, int resid);
```

And in your case, it is:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.silent_1);
```

For more solutions, you can have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48342526/where-to-put-media-resource-and-start-media-player).

**Update**:

[image]

Comment: Hello, is this done in android project? Because i have tried MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.silent_1);  yesterday however this is unknown and Resource.Raw.silent_1 doesn't contain silent_1 even thought it does. Had the same issue when i worked with resources folder before and i solved it by dependency service.

Comment: @ibalginorbit Please see my updated screenshot, does your raw folder looks like that? The name is start with lower "r"(raw).

Comment: i have updated it to Upper R, build the solution but still cant reach it. However this wont work anyway since i cant use this in the static method

Comment: Please use a lowercase “r”. And why you cant use this in the static method? Just change this to Android.App.Application.Context.

Comment: . My Resource.Raw. contains only Equal,GetObject, FromArray, referenceequals

Comment: Sorry. I cant acces the raw file at all. If I use Resource.raw or Resources.raw bot times the file is not accesible

Comment: I have also tried to access the folder thsi way  pausesPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://AT/Resources/raw/silent_1.mp3")); and still return null

Comment: When you say you can't access the file, does it mean you get a error?

Comment: Yes, red underline, i have just created a simple test in another app just to see if i can access the file in android projects from shared project and no. I am still getting the same red underline. I have added a screen shot

Comment: After you add the folder, please clean and rebuild your project then try again.

Comment: i have tried that several times, but i will try once again.

Comment: You have no issue to access the file from shared project. I have tried it and still nothin.

Comment: I upload [a sample project](https://github.com/XfHua/test-Android), please check.

Comment: Thank you, i am sorry, maybe i have explained myself incorrectly i was trying to access the file from shared project not in the MainActivity.

Comment: No, you can't do that in shared project. You can only do that in Android.project as it is api of Android not xamarin.forms.

Comment: So how can i then use it in my shared project?

Comment: You want to play a video in shared project? Have a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement).

Comment: an article, this method is needed for setting a pause between sentences. So the file contains a pause for one to five seconds

Comment: You can't use method of Android in shared project.

Comment: Can i ask you something related to this? I have done what you suggested it work fine, however i have one class responsible for this media player and i am initializing the media player once as static. However now when i am setting the pause in droid project the media player always returns null.

Comment: i have tried to set the media player as parametr but its still null

Comment: I need to see your code and then I can help you better. If my answer helps you, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).  If you have a new question, you can also open a new thread and I will support you there.

Comment: ok, my new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574497/media-played-from-dependency-services-returns-null